# Can system.js replace require.js

Tags: requirejs, amd, systemjs

I'm using requirejs in a large project. This project will soon be upgraded to angular2.

Angular2 uses system.js, so I'm thinking of switching to system.js too. Should I be able to remove the reference to the requirejs library and include system.js instead and expect it to work, or is there something I don't understand here?

I tried by just removing the require.js file and adding the system.js file instead, but I get error messages saying define is not defined.
Can you help? Will I need require.js in addition to system.js?

Comment: Does Angular 2.0 still use SystemJS or is it also compatible with Webpack?

Comment: It is compatible with both

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just switched to system.js too. You need to replace your require.js with system.js and add simple script tag. So it should look like this:

```
<script src="~/lib/system.js/dist/system.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>  
    // set our baseURL reference path
    System.config({
        baseURL: '/app'
    });
    System.import('startup.js');
</script>
```

Comment: And you got it working without changing anything in the existing files that uses requirejs from before?

Comment: Yeah, which version of system.js do you use?

Comment: I got it working. The problem was that the define function and the require function was not available on the global scope. I had to do like this: window.define = System.amdDefine;
window.require = window.requirejs = System.amdRequire;

Comment: what do you do if you get `system.js:4 Uncaught (in promise) Error: (SystemJS) ReferenceError: require is not defined(…)`

Comment: Thanks for the `window.require = window.requirejs = System.amdRequire;` recommendation. But how to use my old `requirejs.config({...})`?

Comment: @Sigfried this might be usefull: https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#map-config and https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/production-workflows.md#bundle-extension

Answer (score 3):

in addition to above steps set

`System.defaultJSExtensions = true;`

by default `systemjs` is not adding extension `.js`