# SystemJS versioning for production and cache management (requirejs urlArgs alternative)

Tags: caching, requirejs, amd, systemjs

I would like to migrate to SystemJS from requirejs however I am failing to find a solution as requirejs have for module versioning.
For example in production (ASP.Net website) I have set RequireJS like this:

```
require.config({
            baseUrl: "@Url.Content("~/Scripts/")",
            urlArgs: "buildNumber=@(File.GetLastWriteTime(ViewContext.Controller.GetType().Assembly.Location).ToBinary().ToString() + typeof(Foundation.MvcApplication).Assembly.GetName().Version)",
            ...
});
```

It guarantees that the file will be reloaded once the project is republished in the production environment, and kept that way until it is reloaded.

However, I did not find any solution for this for SystemJS (As SystemJS manage more types of modules, I would like to migrate to it).

Has anyone used SystemJS in production and had the same issue, do you know an "urlArgs" parameter (or plugin) in SystemJS?

Comment: I don't really understand you question? --- P.S. I am using only requireJS and caching everything up to 365 days. All working well, why do you need systemJS in the first place?

Comment: I've edited the post, it's only to know if anyone has found a parameter/plugin to have the same urlArgs behavior of RequireJS.
SystemJS let us use many types of module definition, so I find it more "future-proof".

Comment: I understand now, it seem like you can found your answer over here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33332911/can-system-js-replace-require-js

Comment: There is no urlArgs parameter or similar plugin in this answer.

Comment: Terribly sorry for mistaken... I will instead prepare an answer for you really quick ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Long story short: there were issues on github of `SystemJS` about  [**cache bust**](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/172). But thing are not offically implemeted yet. At the moment there is a custom hook, which can be easily added

```js
var buildNumber = 1234, // made your own build number
    systemLocate = System.locate;
System.locate = function(load) {
  return Promise.resolve(systemLocate.call(this, load)).then(function(address) {
    return address + '?build='+buildNumber;
  });
}
```

**EDIT** fix typo

Comment: In fact the maker of SystemJS said it was not going to be implemented on SystemJS, saying "caching should be handled at the server layers not the loader layer".

Comment: Doesn’t work since 0.20: https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/1616

Comment: I have 0.19 and this method works great. Thanks a lot for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

I'm on .19 still and for my purposes wanted to control caching for specific files actually in the import, not by a setting per file or globally, etc. but literally when I make the import I want to control it (like how you would normally do with Query Strings).

So just to offer a slight adaptation of the above that I think fits for a lot of people wanting to do it this way - you can just conventionally include 'NO-CACHE' or something in any import and the hook will add a timestamp to break cache. This allows you to call a module with cache from one place but without it from another. Also it let's you break cache anytime you need to on dynamic imports, even dynamically.

```javascript
var systemLocate = System.locate;
System.locate = function (load) {
    return Promise.resolve(systemLocate.call(this, load)).then(function (address) {
        if (address.includes('NO-CACHE'))
            return address.replace('NO-CACHE', '') + '?q=' + new Date(Date.now()).getTime();
        return address;
    });
};

// Example Import with NO-CACHE - can be placed anywhere in path
System.import('NO-CACHE../config.json!').then(config => {
    window.appVersion = config.version;
});
```