# How to load JavaScript on-demand bundles without downloading same library twice in SystemJS?

Tags: reactjs, module, ecmascript-6, systemjs, systemjs-builder

Let's say, I have a `React` project and the main entry point is `app.js`. Where I include `React`, `React-DOM` and `jQuery` like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
...
```

Now imagine I have some routes defined here which will cause it to trigger `route1.js`, `route2.js` etc. on demand like this:

```
SystemJS.import('route1.js');
```

Now, I use `jspm` to bundle my codes like this (Say, besides `react` and `react-dom` my `app.js` also imports many custom written bundles). So, when I bundle `app.js` in bundles up all the libraries and custom modules together to say `build.js`.

```
jspm bundle app.js build.js
```

Now, there are code inside `build.js` which will trigger loading of the `route1.js`, `route2.js` etc. on demand. However, `route1.js` and `route2.js` alos use ES6 imports of `react` and `react-dom`. Now I could of course use `webpack` or `jspm` to also bundle up these `route1.js`, `route2.js` etc. Look, that I have already included the `react` and `react-dom` libraries in `build.js`, only fetching new `route1.js`, `route2.js`. I do not want to include the same libraries inside `route1.js` or `route2.js` because I have already downloaded it once inside `app.js`. But only fetching `rout1.js` or `route.js` as they are (with ES6 import statements) won't work because browser do not understand this.

How do I make

- load code on demand at the same time using ES6 code in development
- do not download the same libraries multiple times

Comment: The files should be cached by the browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SystemJS versionning for production and cache management (requirejs urlArgs alternative)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35404460/systemjs-versionning-for-production-and-cache-management-requirejs-urlargs-alte)